# Accessing DOM via JS from internet explorer contextmenu

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, contextmenu

I want to manipulate DOM via javascript from the context menu of Internet Explorer. To do this, I created the key in registry as:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MenuExt\Remove Node]
@="javascript:var d=document,h=d.head,b=d.body,css='<style>tr{border:solid 1px red;}</style>';h.innerHTML.indexOf(css)==-1?h.innerHTML+=css:h.innerHTML=h.innerHTML.replace(css,'');b.addEventListener('mousedown',function(c){var t=c.target;if(c.ctrlKey){c.preventDefault();t.style.display='none';}});void(0);"
"Contexts"=dword:00000001
```

But it didn't work with the error like: "*document reference is undefined or empty*". Then I tried more simple such as *alert('something')* which properly appeared as "*something*". I also tried more simple DOM reference, such as *alert(document.title)* returned empty.

How can I access a DOM element from context menu of Internet Explorer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think what you are referring to is [HTMLElement.contextMenu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contextMenu), right? As the documentation shows, it has been deprecated. And IE has also been retired, I suggest you pay more attention to modern browsers, such as Chrome or Microsoft Edge. In addition, if you can provide the html code and describe your needs in detail, it will help to solve the problem.

Comment: No I don't. I'm trying to run javascript from Internet Explorer's standard context menu to manipulating DOM elements in an application which uses still Internet Explorer (as MSHTML.dll).

Comment: Well, I'm glad you've solved your problem. You can post it as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer, which will also help other community members with similar problems. By the way, if you have a new question, I suggest you can post it in a new thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the problem myself by using an external html file instead
javascript URI. If someone needs it, they should do like this:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MenuExt\Remove Node]
@="c:\path\to\the_html_file.html"
"Contexts"=dword:00000001
```

And the the_html_file.html file:

```
<html>
<script language="javascript" defer>
var docment=window.external.menuArguments.document;
// now it works!
alert(docment.title);
</script>
</html>
```

For more information: [Adding Entries to the Standard Context Menu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa753589(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)